# Issue when modifying item price in Sale Order (Odoo 13)

Tags: odoo-13

I'm facing that issue:
I have created a new sale order and want to change the price of an item, i edit the item, changed the price and saved but no change was observed on that line but when i added a new line with the same item it display the news price (See attached)

How i can fix that ?

Thanks in Adavance

Comment: seems like you've forgotten to add an attachment

Answer (score 0):

The `pricelist` will only affect once this is **modified once**: `['product_id']` So this having on the line so if you modified on an existing line or check with a new line then it has an effect.

You can check this [method](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/sale/models/sale.py#L1576) which can trigger for change in line price with pricelist.